# How to specify version type in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to index a document as shown below.

```
curl -s -XPUT -H"content-type:application/json" -d@data.json localhost:9200/contacts/_doc/1?version=7&version_type=external
```

Unfortunately this results in version conflict.
Elasticsearch documentation says that I should pass `version_type` as `external` when I use an external version. But I'm not sure how to do this as its not supporting this as a query parameter.

How do I specify `version_type` as external?

EDIT: current version of the document is 5. But according to [es documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#index-versioning), when version_type `external` is used, any higher version should work. Which means 7 should be able to overwrite 5. But as I'm getting version conflict I assume that es is not taking the `version_type` parameter that I'm specifying.

SOLVED: I had to put the URL given to curl in quotes. Bash took the `&` in in URL, took rest of it as new command and set `version_type` as an environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your curl command looks correct. The conflict can come because of the different versions of the document.

I would guess that the current version of the document is not 7 and hence it throws the version conflict.

Can you post the current version of this same document? Is it 7 ?

Comment: Updated the question with more details.

Comment: Could you update the question with the structure of your document?